# How to see all edited files of perticular Version ID in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, version, history, git-stage

I wanted to see all lastly committed files of specific version ID. I'm using git repository and eclipse Kepler.

e.g. I have some.jspx file of version ID 'xyznumber', I wanted to see all the files who got committed with this same version ID.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse we can achieve the same by looking into 'Team > Show in History' on particular module. we can see our all committed changes of required version.